# Arithmetic operation on Byte Arrays

Tags: arrays, math, byte

I know that in modern languages we have Classes like BigInteger which can be used to make arithmetics operation on huge integers. But how are those operations done in the byte-level?

Example:
If I have those two Hex values:

```
input1 = a0c846e4e4be306fd15265f49693be9acaddf68bf6d21aaf1ef1990add502ccf
input2 = d7d2c635df4791d9e04fec979eefbab2bef500df9332076b538bd5b653f5b388
```

If I add them using BigInteger class I would have the following output:

```
output = 1789b0d1ac405c249b1a2528c3583794d89d2f76b8a04221a727d6ec13145e057
```

My question is: How can I make the very same addition (and other arithmetics operations) using byte arrays? I mean get those inputs (1 and 2) convert it to two byte arrays, how can I make the arithmetic addition to have the same output as BitInteger addition?

Comment: The topic is, I fear, too complex to be answerable using this site's Q&A format. However, you should be able to get a start simply by adapting the methods you learned in school for basic arithmetic operations to your favorite computer language. Start with addition, and remember how "carries" work.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bitkeeper-scm/tcl/blob/master/libtommath/tommath.pdf) is a reasonable tutorial.